# ¿Cómo paso una matriz de dimensiones NxN a una función?

Tags: c, matrices

Estoy trabajando en un trabajo de la universidad donde tengo que generar una matriz de dimensiones NxN donde su tamaño es especificado por el usuario.

Entonces, ¿cómo se debe declarar la función que pueda recibir `matriz[n][n]`, por ejemplo, para que la función `imprimirMatriz` pueda funcionar?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int **mat1 = NULL, i, j, n;

void generarMatriz() {
printf("Introduzca el tamanho para las matrices: ");
scanf("%d", &n);
mat1 = (int **) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
if (mat1 == NULL) {
    perror("Error");
}

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    mat1[i] = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if (mat1[i] == NULL)) {
        perror("Error");
    }
}
}
void imprimirMatriz(int matriz[][], int n) { //siendo que el problema es en el segundo corchete, que no puede quedar vacio
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        printf("%d ", matriz[i][j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}   
}
int main() {
generarMatriz();
imprimirMatriz(&mat1, n);
free(mat1);
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Cambia `int matriz[][]` por `int **matriz`. Por otro lado, no deberías tener variables globales. Deberían ser locales de `main()`.

Comment: Ya que estamos en C, creo que el siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16672322/8781554) es relevante.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Un poco de teoría.

El C no tiene arrays dinámicos (cuyo tamaño se elige en tiempo de ejecución) propiamente dichos, pero puede construirlos mediante punteros.

### Arrays unidimensionales

Para un array unidimemsional (también llamado vector), se utiliza `malloc()` para reservar tanta memoria como sea necesaria para sus elementos. A malloc debe pasársele el tamaño en *bytes*, por lo que si cada elemento es, por ejemplo, de tipo entero y necesitamos `N` elementos, la inicialización sería:

```c
int *vector_dinamico;
int N = 50;
vector_dinamico = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Una vez inicializado el puntero, podemos desreferenciarlo (poner un `*` delante) para acceder al primer elemento del array, por ejemplo, para asignar un cero a ese elemento: `*vector_dinamico=0;`, pero ¿y los elementos siguientes?

Gracias a que C tiene lo que se denomina *aritmética de punteros* puedes sumarle un índice `i` al puntero para obtener la dirección de memoria en la que estaría el elemento `i`-ésimo. Es decir `(vector_dinamico+i)` te dará la dirección del elemento `i`-ésimo. Para asignarle un valor puedes desreferenciar esa dirección y poner por ejemplo: `*(vector_dinamico+i)=0;`

Un bucle que inicialice con ceros todos los elementos de este vector sería por tanto:

```c
for (int i=0; i<N, i++) 
  *(vector_dinamico+i) = 0;
```

Probablemente no hayas visto muchas veces esta sintaxis, debido a que es un poco incómoda y el C permite otra sintaxis alternativa que es la siguiente:

```c
for (int i=0; i<N, i++) 
  vector_dinamico[i] = 0;
```

Esta sintaxis tiene como ventaja que es idéntica a la de los arrays. Pero tiene como inconveniente que es idéntica a la de los arrays :-) por lo que muchos programadores noveles confunden ambas cosas. En realidad `vector_dinamico` no es un array, sino un puntero a una zona de memoria donde hay un array. El hecho de que podamos usar la sintaxis `a[i]` se debe a que el compilador automáticamente la traduce a `*(a+i)`.

También, para acabar de liar al programador novato, el compilador admite las dos sintaxis siguientes como equivalentes a la hora de definir una función que recibe como parámetro un vector dinámico:

```c
int sumar_elementos(int *vector, int n_elem);
// Es equivalente a
int sumar_elementos(int vector[], int n_elem);
```

De nuevo la existencia de estas dos sintaxis equivalentes ayuda a reforzar la errónea idea de que arrays y punteros vienen a ser lo mismo.

### Arrays bidimensionales

Un array bidimensional (matriz) puede entenderse como un vector en el que cada uno de sus elementos es una fila de la matriz, es decir, otro vector.

Con esta idea en la cabeza, ya que cada fila de la matriz es un vector unidimensional, cada fila se gestionará mediante un puntero que apuntará a los datos de esa fila. Por otro lado, el "array bidimensional" no será más que un array cuyos elementos son esos punteros.

Si supiéramos de antemano cuántas filas tiene nuestra matriz, podríamos crear un array de tamaño fijo con ese número de elementos, siendo cada uno de ellos un puntero. Por ejmplo, suponiendo que hay 10 filas:

```c
int *array_dinamico[10];
```

Esto está declarando un vector de 10 elementos, siendo cada uno de ellos de tipo `int *`, es decir, un puntero (que haremos apuntar a cada fila de la matriz).

Ya que `array_dinamico` es un array, podría usar la sintaxis "normal" para acceder a sus elementos, y así `array_dinamico[0]` me permitiría obtener el primer elemento de ese vector, que es un puntero al vector que contiene los enteros de la primera fila de la matriz. Ya que `array_dinamico[0]` es un puntero a entero, puedo usar la sintaxis `*(array_dinamico[0]+i)` para acceder al elemento `i`-ésimo de esa fila. Por tanto, de forma general puedo usar `*(array_dinamico[j]+i)` para acceder al elemento `i`-ésimo de la fila `j`-ésima.

De nuevo esa sintaxis no suele verse mucho, porque en su lugar se usa esta otra, mucho más agradable: `array_dinamico[j][i]`. El que esta sintaxis sea válida se deduce de lo ya dicho antes sobre arrays unidimensionales.

Pero ¿y si el número de filas del array tampoco es conocido de antemano sino que queremos elegirlo en tiempo de ejecución? En ese caso ya no podemos declararlo poniendo un `[10]`.

Usaremos la misma técnica vista para los arrays unidimensionales. Allí, cuando queríamos reservar dinámicamente `N` elementos, usamos un `malloc()` para crear memoria para ellos. Podemos hacer lo mismo aqui, pero teniendo en cuenta que ahora cada elemento es de tipo `int*` (el puntero a la fila). Por tanto el puntero a mi array será de tipo `int**` (puntero a puntero).

Así por ejemplo, si `M` es el número de filas de la matriz:

```c
int **array_dinamico;
int M = 8;
array_dinamico = malloc(M*sizeof(int *));
```

Esto reserva espacio para los 8 punteros correspondientes a las 8 filas de la matriz que estamos creando. Pero esos 8 punteros no tienen aún ningún valor porque no hemos creado ninguna de las 8 filas. Para ello habría que llamar otras 8 veces a `malloc()`, para crear cada fila, y guardar el valor retornado en cada elemento del array. Así por ejemplo:

```py
for (int i = 0; i<M, i++)
   array_dinamico[i] = malloc(N*sizeof(int));
```

Con todo esto tendríamos el array de M filas y N columnas ya reservado dinámicamente, aunque no hemos inicializado aún sus valores.

### Paso de estos arrays como parámetro

Ya vimos que en el caso de arrays unidimensionales el C permite declarar los parámetros con dos sintaxis equivalentes: `int *param`, o bien `int param[]`. Ambas son lo mismo porque el compilador sabe lo que necesita saber para compilar una expresión como `param[5]`. Sabe que `param` apunta al comienzo del array y que cada elemento es de tipo `int`, por lo que puede calcular cuántos bytes debe avanzar dentro del array para llegar al elemento 5.

En cambio si el array es bidimensional, algo como `int param[][]` no le sirve al compilador, pues ¿cuántos bytes debe desplazarse para llegar a `param[5]` en este caso? Para poder calcularlo necesitaría conocer el tamaño de cada fila, y eso no aparece en la declaración.

Podemos arreglar esa declaración si la cambiamos por esta otra: `int *param[]`. Aquí le decimos que el parámetro es un vector en el que cada elemento es de tipo `int*`. Ahora sí puede saber que para llegar a `param[5]` debe añadirle a la dirección de comienzo (`param`) el tamaño de un puntero multiplicado por 5. Una vez llega a ese elemento, tendremos un puntero a la fila correspondiente, por lo que la expresión `param[5][3]` también podría compilarla correctamente (iría a la dirección indicada por `param` más cinco veces el tamaño de un puntero, y de ahí extraería otro puntero, al que le sumaría 3 veces el tamaño de un entero para llegar finalmente al valor buscado).

## Respondiendo ya a tu pregunta

Disculpa por la larga excursión antes de llegar a lo que te interesa, pero de este modo queda ya escrito y explicado el asunto de punteros y arrays, por si en el futuro tengo que redirigir a alguien más a esta pregunta :-)

Con lo anterior ha quedado explicado por qué `void imprimirMatriz(int matriz[][], int n)` no funcionaba.

En base a lo anterior, se deduce que tienes dos posibles soluciones, ambas equivalentes (es mera cuestión de gustos el elegir una u otra):

```c
void imprimiMatriz(int *matriz[], int n)
// O, equivalentemente
void imprimirMatriz(int **matriz, int n)
```

**Postdata**. Tu programa tiene otros errores.

Cuando llamas a `imprimirMatriz` tienes que pasarle la dirección a que apunta el puntero `mat1`, pues ahí es donde está el vector de punteros (cada uno a una fila). 
En cambio le pasas `&mat1`, que no es la dirección a la que apunta el puntero, sino la dirección *en que se almacena el puntero*. Eso está mal, pero el error es comprensible debido a la fácil confusión entre punteros y arrays, debido al *syntactic sugar* del C.

Otro error que tienes es que no liberas memoria correctamente. Aunque haces `free(mat1)`, esto sólo libera la memoria que creaste para el "vector de punteros a filas", pero necesitas llamar otras `N` veces a `free()` para liberar cada uno de esos punteros. De hecho, tienes que liberar *primero* cada una de las filas y después el puntero "principal" (pues si lo haces en orden inverso, una vez liberado el puntero general ya no podrías acceder a los punteros de cada fila).

Comment: _Esta sintaxis tiene como ventaja que es idéntica a la de los arrays. Pero tiene como inconveniente que es idéntica a la de los arrays_ ¿Se te ha escapado? :P

Comment: @NaCl No, qué va. Es completamente intencional :-)

Comment: En **Paso de estos arrays como parámetro** no estoy de acuerdo del todo... la sintaxis `int param[][]` es **casi** valida para arrays declarados... **en la pila**. Digo *casi* porque en este caso habría que indicar el tamaño de la segunda dimensión: `int param[][10]`... los arrays en la pila se estructuran de forma diferente a los arrays dinámicos y eso provoca diferencias al pasarlos como parámetros

Comment: La sintaxis de los arrays de tamaño fijo es así porque en memoria se almacenan de forma lineal y el compilador necesita conocer el tamaño de cada *columna* para calcular los saltos correspondientes. Un array doble dinámico tiene dos indirecciones mientras que uno array doble en la pila solo tiene una...

Comment: entonces @abulafia, como debo pasar el parametro para que sea la dirección a que apunta el puntero mat1

Comment: @DanielVelázquez Simplemente quita el `&` de delante. El valor de un puntero es la dirección a la que apunta.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! problema resuelto.