# Array de punteros en C

Tags: c, array, punteros

una consulta tengo una duda si alguien puede ayudarme. Cómo seria el prototipo de una función que recibe como parámetro un array de punteros? Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Suponiendo, por ejemplo, que la función retorna un entero, y los punteros del array en cuestión son también punteros a entero, la declaración podría ser: `int funcion(int **array)`, o también `int funcion(int *array[])`. Son equivalentes. Para más detalles mira [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143253/7123)

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como ejemplo una función que retorne un entero y que reciba un array de punteros a objetos de cualquier tipo sería de la siguiente manera:

```
int NombreFuncion(void *array[])
```

**ó**

```
int NombreFuncion(void **array)
```

Si el array es de punteros de otro tipo de variable, solo tendrías que cambiar el tipo "void" dentro de los paréntesis, por ejemplo para un array de punteros a int:

```
int NombreFuncion(int *array[])
```

**ó**

```
int NombreFuncion(int **array)
```

Te recomiendo esta página en donde alguien explica mejor el tema: http://c.conclase.net/curso/index.php?cap=017#inicio

> Por ejemplo, crearemos una tabla dinámicamente. Para ello se usan los
>   punteros a punteros.
>
> Veamos la declaración de un puntero a puntero:
>
> ```
> int **tabla;
> ```
>
> "tabla" es un puntero que apunta a un objeto de tipo puntero a int.