# ¿Cómo puedo poner un array como parámetro de una función en C?

Tags: c

Tengo el siguiente **código**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void mostrarMatriz(int, char[][]);

void main(int argc, char* args[]){
        mostrarMatriz(argc, args);
}

void mostrarMatriz(int filas, char matriz[][]){

        for(int i=0; i<filas; i++){
                int columnas = sizeof(matriz[i])/sizeof(char);
                for(int j=0; j<columnas; j++){
                        printf("%c\t", matriz[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
        }

}
```

Y me salen los siguientes **errores**:

[image: Errores C]

Por lo que sé de C, debo declarar previamente la función. Esta está declarada, pero **no reconoce la declaración de la matriz de caracteres. No entiendo a qué se debe ni si el resto de errores son consecuencia de esta errónea declaración.**

El objetivo del programa es sacar por pantalla los argumentos de llamada del programa. Por ejemplo, suponiendo que el programa se llame Azul, tenemos:

```
$Azul Hola 34
A    z    u    l
H    o    l    a
3    4
```

Gracias por su atención.

Comment: Puede resultarte útil también esta respuesta -> https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/143253/7123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toma la declaración:

```
char matriz[][];
```

Este es un array, al que no le indicas el tamaño, y que sus elementos son de tipo `char[]`. El problema radica en que `char[]` es un tipo incompleto. Según el estándar, si no se indica el tamaño del array, es un tipo incompleto, y el tipo de los elementos de un array no pueden ser de tipo incompleto. Si quieres una explicación en mas detalle, te recomiendo que veas [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10003270/gcc-array-type-has-incomplete-element-type).

Una solución podría ser volverlo un tipo completo dándole un tamaño al array, pero esto no parece ser posible ya que las cantidades dependen de una entrada del usuario, una que no tenemos disponible en tiempo de compilación.

La otra opción seria tomar el parámetro exactamente igual que como lo tomas en el `main`:

```
//                            No char[][], sino char*[]
void mostrarMatriz(int filas, char *matriz[]);
```

**Nota:** La forma correcta de tomar el tamaño no es:

```
int columnas = sizeof(matriz[i])/sizeof(char);
```

Esto solo funciona si el tamaño del array es conocido en tiempo de compilación. La forma correcta de obtener el tamaño seria usando `strlen`.

El código corregido seria:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void mostrarMatriz(int, char *[]);

int main(int argc, char *args[]) {
    mostrarMatriz(argc, args);
    return 0;
}

void mostrarMatriz(int filas, char *matriz[]) {

    // En el ejemplo, no se miraba que imprimiera el nombre del programa, asi
    // que supongo que querias empezar por 1 y no por 0
    for (int i = 1; i < filas; i++) {
        int columnas = strlen(matriz[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            printf("%c\t", matriz[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Mañana adaptaré mi programa (que es más grande que la simplificación expuesta en mi pregunta) a lo que usted me ha enseñado para ver si resulta bien. Si no es mañana, será el miércoles como tarde cuando reciba respuesta de mi parte. Gracias.

Comment: @SergioDuránVega Perfecto, si te topas con cualquier otro problema estaré pendiente. Muchas gracias por reducir el problema para hacer sencilla la pregunta, eso nos ayuda bastante.

Comment: El problema queda resuelto. Entiendo que el programa debe reservar la memoria de las matrices en tiempo de compilación y si esta tiene n dimensiones entonces debe conocer la longitud de las (n-1)-últimas para hacer sus cálculos. Es por eso que un vector lo acepta sin más. No tiene problemas con la primera dimensión, pues siempre puede encadenar la pila del vector con otra dirección de memoria si tiene problemas de espacio, por ejemplo (vaga explicación, pero creo que resume decentemente lo que entiendo).

Comment: Mi programa funciona en cuanto al problema expuesto en esta pregunta. Sin embargo, contiene un último fallo. Sé que es el último porque surge en el menor de los ámbitos: lo demás está todo bien. El problema es similar a este de las matrices, solo que con macros. Lo preguntaré en el foro en unos minutos o, como tarde, mañana (por si le interesa). Muchas gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Lo que sí me gustaría saber es si entendí bien la idea del problema.

Comment: Estaré pendiente a tu próximo post. Honestamente, no logre entender muy bien la forma en la que entendiste tu el problema.

Comment: Al final logré resolver el problema con la macro, luego no habrá post. Gracias igualmente por su interés

Answer (score 1):

En C tienes que declarar el tamaño del array. En caso de ser bidimensional puedes declararlo de la siguiente manera:

```
void fucntion(int filas, int columnas, int a[][columnas]) {}
```